# 12bit signed value handling in 16 bit variable

Tags: variables, signed, shift, unsigned-integer

I have 12bit signed value. What is the correct way to store this 12bit signed value in 16bit variable? MSB bit has to be moved to 15th bit position?

```
converted_Temperature = (Tmp_value & (1<<11)) <<4; 

converted_Temperature +=  (Tmp_value & ((1<<11)-1)) * 6.25;
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to convert q12 to q16 ([Q_(number_format)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29)) you must copy sign bit to all high bits (11-15):

```
   int16_t q12, q16;
   q16 = (q12 & 0x0800) ? (q12 | 0xf800) : q12;
```